# What is the optimal usage of Bandwidth for a Signaling server?

Tags: licode

We are using Licode for a Audio/Video conferencing solution. For a conference room with 15 members (audio only, without video), the bandwidth usage of the Signaling Server is in the range of 4 MB/sec (Out) and 750 KB/sec (In). Is this expected regular usage or should it be less?

Also, is there a baseline, with which we can compare against?